# Show Popup window based on referring URL

Tags: javascript, url, popup, modal-dialog, refer

If the link the user clicks on is: /user/login.jsp?focus=login then they will go to the normal login page.

If the link the user clicks is: /user/login.jsp?focus=login&CTCampName=Apple then they will go the login page but a popup window will pop giving them information.

Thank you all very very much!

Comment: Well, looks like you have to extract the query string off of your URL, window.location.search, is one way you ca do the check, and write some regex to match what you expect from the URL.

Comment: @gcampbell I am setting it up right now in Test&Target by targeting the campaign with Current URL Contains and then adding tracking into the original URL that matches...and then just using <BODY onLoad="alert('hello world!')"> ... because I am not too familiar with JavaScript, though I think it would be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the Test and Target method. Thank you.